# Debuggind in PDT with XDebug

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I installed and configured XDebug, then tried to configure PDT to work with it. Running PHP file as a script works just fine. Running it as a web page fails: "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Here are my PHP settings in Eclipse:
[image]
[image]
[image]

What can be done to make debugging as web page work?

Comment: A screen-shot of "Debug Configurations ..." might be helpful to see what's wrong. Seems like Eclipse generates a useless URL from the filepath. Maybe deactivate "Auto Generate" and enter the proper URL yourself.

Comment: Which URL does it use/open? Use i.e. Wireshark to find it if it is not visible.